# Is using "jquery-latest.min.js" bad practice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So the title says it. Is it bad practice to use `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` when I want to include Jquery in my page?

I asked this question because nowhere in the Jquery, Google, and Microsoft websites they provide such a link. Rather they put versioned links like this `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`. That's why I thought maybe they do not want people to use that link.

And if it is bad practice, why is that? and what is the solution to keep up with these version changes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using a "latest" jQuery in a production environment wouldn't be very smart, as your web site would stop working if breaking changes occur. You always want to know which jQuery version you are writing your web site's code against.

Updating to a new jQuery version should always be a manual process for that reason. It would ideally look something like this:

- Look at the change log or upgrade guide of the new version ([example](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#changes-of-note-in-jquery-1-9))
- Fix any issues in your code that the new version might cause
- Start using the new version on an internal / development version of the web site
- Test it thoroughly
- When all is well, switch the production site to using the new version.

Comment: Heh, just as a point of reference look at the upgrade from 1.9 to 2.x - that alone should keep folks from 'just using the latest'.

Comment: True. So what is the purpose this file (`jquery-latest.min.js`)? Who should use it? Why they provided it in the first place?

Comment: @Hesam perhaps for people running development environments, or for those who frequently check whether a new version is out. I'm sure there are people using the "latest" link for some reason - it just has no business on a live web site

Answer (score 1):

A good option is use the official jquery.min.js version 3.6.0

```
<script src="https://jquery-min.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessarily bad practice, but using the Google API version is recommended. The reason being is that many people visiting your sites will already have a cached version of the Google jquery, making your site load faster. Plus, there is a very very slim chance google will go down.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is bad practice because occasionally there are breaking releases, which you wouldn't find out about until it is too late.

As far as updating Jquery, I wouldn't suggest updating it until you needed a newer version specifically for a feature or bugfix.